# Couchbase parameterized N1QL query IN statement

Tags: java, couchbase, sql++

Using `com.couchbase.client, java-client` version `2.2.7` I have been unable to get a n1ql query working that uses an IN statement with multiple items see my example query and java code below

```
public int getCountForDuration(Long startTime, Long endTime, String ids){
    JsonObject placeHolders = JsonObject.create().put("ids", ids).put("startTime", startTime).put("endTime", endTime);
    N1qlQuery query = N1qlQuery.parameterized(COUNT_STATEMENT, placeHolders)            
    N1qlQueryResult result = bucket.query(query);
    ...
}

public static final String COUNT_STATEMENT = "select count(*) as count " +
            "from bucketName " +
            "where docType = 'docId' " +
            "and (id IN [$ids]) " + <----- OFFENDING LINE
            "and publishTimestamp between $startTime and $endTime";
```

I've tried setting `ids`  using ('), ("), and (`) such as:

```
ids = "'123', '456'";
ids = "\"123\" , \"456\";
ids = "`123`,`456`";
```

None of these are working when there are multiple ids however if there is only one such as `ids = "'123'"` it works fine. Also my query works if I use it using CBQ on the terminal.

> My question is this how do I crate a parameterized N1QL query which
>   can take multiple items in an IN statement?

Comment: misplaced the brackets should be "and ( id IN ([$ids]) ) "

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Removing the brackets around the `$ids` in the statement and putting the actual ids into `placeholders` as a `JsonArray` object should work:

```
JsonObject placeHolders = JsonObject.create()
    .put("ids", JsonArray.from("id1", "id2", "id3"))
    .put("startTime", startTime)
    .put("endTime", endTime);
```

Comment: Hey Simon can you take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38845615/n1ql-query-times-out-on-aws-server couchbase collectInfo logs here  https://s3.amazonaws.com/cb-customers/TE2/ thanks in advance.

Comment: How do I set such placeholder in Spring Data?

eg. I have:

`@Query("#{#n1ql.selectEntity} USE KEYS $ids") Collection<User> findByIdIn(@Param("ids") List ids);`


but calling it via Http I get `"Unsupported type for JsonArray: class java.util.ArrayList"`

the only way I could make it working is:

`@Query("#{#n1ql.selectEntity} USE KEYS $ids") Collection<User> findByIdIn(@Param("ids") JsonArray ids);`

and then defining a custom objectMapper to get a JsonArray from a rest call. Is there a better way?

Comment: I mean using @RepositoryRestResource

Comment: If you're just doing a plain USE KEYS then you might as well use the CrudRepository's `findAll(Iterable)` method

Comment: The query I am using is just for the sake of example. In general I could have custom queries where I need to map an `Iterable` coming from an http call in `@RepositoryRestResource` to query parameter. So currently I see no way to get it working (others that using a custom objectMapper).